# Implementing Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and providing the best possible configuration values

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a for loop in which I need to make a REST call. This loop will iterate over 20,000 times as per my requirement. So, I implemented multithreading by Spring framework's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. The configuration is as below:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <!--<property name="queueCapacity" value="1000" />-->

        <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

What would be the best values for `corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, queueCapacity` to get the best performance? I know it would mostly depend on the CPU. But I just want to get some idea so that the performance can be improved. Any other thoughts also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guide in the official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html)

> This class is also well suited for management and monitoring (e.g. through JMX), providing several useful attributes: "corePoolSize", "maxPoolSize", "keepAliveSeconds" (all supporting updates at runtime); "poolSize", "activeCount" (for introspection only).

But since it support update at run-time. You can easily tune it based on your hardware.